# How to read the realtime notifications from Facebook graph API in callback URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

How to read the realtime notifications from Facebook graph API in callback URL. Below is the code in my callback url. But I don't get any notifications.

```
      if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET" && Request.QueryString["hub.challenge"] != null)
          {
             Response.Clear();
             Response.Write(Request.QueryString["hub.challenge"].ToString());
             Response.End();
          }
          else if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
          {
             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
             string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
           }
```

Comment: As evidenced by the comments conversation below, I think this is unclear, and am recommending putting it on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a subscription in the way that is described in the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/#subscribing?

Check your existing Subscriptions like this:

```
GET /{app-id}/subscriptions
```

as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/subscriptions/#read

Have you implemented some logging for the GET and POST requests, so that you know if requests occur?

Comment: Yes i have created a subscription.

Comment: Hi Tobi. I have successfully created a callback URl. Server will post the notification to my callback url. But I dont get any notifications.

Comment: Which fields did you subscribe to? Did you test it with an User who gave permissions to the app, i.e. subscribing to user->likes and then haveing the User like a new Page?

Comment: I subscribed to Feed. I tested it. I get the subscribed fields.

Comment: So, maybe I didn't understand what the problem is... Can you elaborate`?

Comment: I have subscribed to Feed field. I have set up a call back url. I want real time notifications to be posted by the server to my callback url.

Comment: @Tobi, I have voted to put this question on hold, since it is both unclear and abandoned. Would you do the same? Thanks.